# React native Android app crashes immediately after start

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

My app crashes immediately after startup in release mode but it's working fine when using it in debug mode. List of things that i did to build the apk:

1. creating a keystore file and adding it to `build.gradle` file
2. `cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease`

`build.gradle`:

```
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true // proguard is enabled
.
.
.
android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wallet"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            if (nativeArchitectures) {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters nativeArchitectures.split(',')
                }
            }
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "wallet",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.14",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.8.5",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^3.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.1.12",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-jalaali": "^0.9.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.4",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.4.8",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-flags": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-network-info": "^5.2.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.23",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-touch-id": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "reselect": "^4.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

`proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-keep class com.swmansion.reanimated.** { *; } // Added these two lines because of what they said in reanimated 2 documentation
-keep class com.facebook.react.turbomodule.** { *; }
```

And i ran `adb logcat -d > logs.txt` command to get a list of logs:

```
--------- beginning of crash
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.wallet, PID: 4969
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.swmansion.reanimated.layoutReanimation.NativeMethodsHolder.isLayoutAnimationEnabled()' on a null object reference
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext.handleException(Unknown Source:74)
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext$ExceptionHandlerWrapper.handleException(Unknown Source:2)
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.GuardedRunnable.run(Unknown Source:7)
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.swmansion.reanimated.layoutReanimation.NativeMethodsHolder.isLayoutAnimationEnabled()' on a null object reference
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.swmansion.reanimated.layoutReanimation.AnimationsManager.isLayoutAnimationEnabled(Unknown Source:2)
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.swmansion.reanimated.layoutReanimation.ReaLayoutAnimator.isLayoutAnimationEnabled(Unknown Source:5)
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.swmansion.reanimated.layoutReanimation.ReanimatedNativeHierarchyManager.manageChildren(Unknown Source:11)
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.z0$m.b(Unknown Source:14)
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.z0$a.run(Unknown Source:135)
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.z0.U(Unknown Source:53)
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.z0.s(Unknown Source:0)
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.z0$b.runGuarded(Unknown Source:2)
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.GuardedRunnable.run(Unknown Source:0)
01-11 15:34:02.883  4969  4969 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 7 more
```

Apparently, `Reanimated` is the thing that is causing the problem. But how can i fix this? Much appreciated

Comment: https://github.com/software-mansion-labs/reanimated-2-playground/commit/71642dbe7bd96eb41df5b9f59d661ab15f6fc3f8 , does this solve it for you?

Comment: I fixed it by disabling proguard. I'll test the link you shared. Thanks

Comment: @ardalan, I’m having a similar issue. Did the link as shared work for you???

Comment: @HansBouwmeester Well, as much as i remember, i didn't do what the link said. I just disabled `proguard` and the problem got fixed. But crashing app in the beginning can be caused by many things. You should try using `adb logcat` and find the related log for your app. Once i had this problem without `proguard`, and after i updated `reanimated 2` to latest version the problem was gone. But you should do `adb logcat` first and see what is causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

To track the issue in release mode, connect your device with Metro. Then run this command

> npx react-native log-android

After that run the following command

> npx react-native run-android --variant=release

Your logs will appear in Metro console.